# How to convert array value into array index with array values remain same in Php

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, associative-array

I have an array like this

```
array(
0 => "bar",
1 => "foo",
);
```

and I want output like this

```
array(
"bar" => "bar",
"foo" => "foo",
);
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Assuming your original array is strictly a numeric array</strike>:

Actually works for non-numeric as well:

```
array_combine($array, $array);
```

http://codepad.org/fxOmIh2D

Answer (score 1):

in case non numeric array

simple logic of using value as key works

```
$array1 = array(
   0 => "bar",
   "cat" => "foo",);
foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    $array1[$value] = $value;
    unset($array1[$key]);
}

var_dump($array1);
```

gives

```
array(2) {
  ["bar"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
}
```

and if its strict use answer above, would be faster i guess and clean code too.

http://codepad.org/x3Z1zLjz

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
0 => "bar",
1 => "foo",
);

$arrCombine = array_combine($arr, $arr);

print_r($arrCombine);
```

```
gives

Array
(
    [bar] => bar
    [foo] => foo
)
```